# SVN repository access control when using svn+ssh protocol

Tags: svn

For my project I need to setup SVN repository access control when accessing it through svn+ssh.

I know that I can do this kind of control setup by using Apache.

Is it possible to do the same kind of branch level access control using svn+ssh?

Thanks,
Rishi.

Comment: Why don't you use Apache instead of svn+ssh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "No", BUT ... depending on your situation, I have a suggestion that might help.

i.e. if you can install Apache on your SVN server, but you can only access the SVN server via SSH, then you could set up an "SSH tunnel" to the Apache server.

So, first set up Apache (say on port 80 on your SVN server), then from your dev computer, set up a tunnel locally (say to listen port 8022, and forward to port 80 on the SVN server), and then you can access the repo using something like:

`svn ls http://localhost:8022/repo-name/....`

You can set up an SSH tunnel using Putty (or using the "ssh -L" option in Linux). Depends on your dev machine.

I have to resort to this when I'm working remotely.

Hopefully that's enough info for you and your friend Google to get a solution.
HTH

Answer (score 3):

use authz

in `/path/to/repo/conf/svnserve.conf`

`authz-db = authz`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I had to figure that out for myself, mind you, but @vinnyjames is exactly correct.  Once you have "authz" turned on, you can then set permissions for your users, on a path-specific basis if needed, according to the svn docs:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Answer (score -2):

I have been also trying this but I think the authz file method only works with svn:// mechanism

Comment: I am not downvoting on purpose as I do not want to discourage you for your first post but this is more like a comment on the question than answer. Please go through help center for what qualifies as a good answer.